# Are the *A Win32 API calls still relevant?

Tags: windows, winapi

I still see advice about using the `LPTSTR`/`TCHAR` types, etc., instead of `LPWSTR`/`WCHAR`. I believe the Unicode stuff was well introduced at Win2k, and I frankly don't write code for Windows 98 anymore. (Excepting special cases, of course.) Given that I don't care about Windows 98 (or, even less, ME) as they're decade old OS, is there any reason to use the compatibility `TCHAR`, etc. types? Why still advise people to use `TCHAR` - what benefit does it add over using `WCHAR` directly?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234365/is-tchar-still-relevant

Comment: I haven't seen developers suggest using `TCHAR`s. I have, however, seen developers suggesting to be consistent. If you call the generic API version (e.g. `CreateFile`), then you need to be consistent and pass an `LPCTSTR`. Are you sure you aren't confusing those?

Answer (score 1):

If someone tells you to walk up to 1,000,000 lines of non-_UNICODE C++, with plenty of declarations using `char` instead of `wchar_t` or `TCHAR` or `WCHAR`, you had better be prepared to cope with the non-Unicode Win32 API. Conversion on a large scale is quite costly, and may not be something the source-o-money is prepared to pay for.

As for new code, well, there's so much example code out there using TCHAR that it may be easier to cut and paste, and there is in some cases some friction between `WCHAR` as `wchar_t` and `WCHAR` as `unsigned short`.

Who knows, maybe some day MS will add a UTF-32 data type under TCHAR?

Comment: Interesting point about the possibility of expanding TCHAR. Unlikely though as UTF-32 is likely to take significantly more space on pretty much every piece of actual text in existence. HTML5 rejects it as an encoding entirely.

Comment: @kib the UTF-32 comment was intended to be humorous.

Comment: @kibibu: afaik it already happened on some platforms. Last time I checked wchar_t was 4 bytes on g++/linux.

Comment: I suppose the question was primarily aimed at new code: If you're using the *A stuff, you're missing out on Unicode entirely anyways. And if you're using char instead of TCHAR or WCHAR, then again, you've got bigger problems.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the unicode versions of functions were introduced with Win32 in 1993 with Windows NT 3.1. In fact, on the NT based oses, almost all the *A functions just convert to Unicode and call the *W version internally. Also, support for the *W functions on 9x does exist through [Microsoft Layer for Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Layer_for_Unicode).

For new programs, I would definately recommend using the TCHAR macros or WCHARs directly. I doubt MS will be adding support for any other character sizes during NT's lifetime. For existing code bases, I guess it would depend on how important it is to support Unicode vs cost of fixing it. The *A functions need to stay in Win32 forever for backward compatibility.