# Making use of WCHAR as a CHAR?

Tags: c++, c

GDI+ makes use of WCHAR instead of what the WinAPI allows which is CHAR. Usually I can do:

```
char *str = "C:/x.bmp";
```

but how do I do this for wchar? I can't juse do

```
wchar_t *file = "C:/x.bmp";
```

Thanks

Comment: Please: On Microsoft Windows, the directory separator character is "\", not "/".

Comment: @Andreas:  In almost all contexts, `/` is usable as a path separator in Windows.

Comment: Andreas Rejbrand, actually, both are allowed.

Comment: I know. But the norm is to use "\". Within Microsoft Windows, "\" is always used.

Comment: @Andreas:  If you are trying to write portable software, it's better to use `/` (assuming you're not using something like Boost.Filesystem to manage platform portability for you.  Also, using `/` allows you to avoid issues with escaping the string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
wchar_t *file = L"C:/x.bmp";
```

L introduces a wide string.

In Windows, it's customary to use macros that behave differently according to some preprocessor definitions. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321(VS.71).aspx

You would write:

```
_TCHAR *file = _TEXT("C:/x.bmp");
```

Comment: And if GDI+ _demands_ `wchar_t` (mind you, I wouldn't know), what does it help to have those macros? They are only good if you want to _switch between `char` and `wchar_t`_. (Since a Unicode-enabled application can do everything an ASCII-only application does, once you have code that deals with Unicode, why would you every switch to ASCII?)

Comment: @sbi see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234365/is-tchar-still-relevant Of course, if GDI+ demans a `WCHAR`, he should pass it a `WCHAR`.

Answer (score 6):

```
const wchar_t *file = L"C:/x.bmp";
```

This is according to C++ Standard 2.13.4/1:

> <...>A string literal that begins with L,
>   such as L"asdf", is a wide string
>   literal. A wide string literal has type “array of n const wchar_t” and has static storage duration, where
>      n is the size of the string as defined below, and is initialized with the given characters.

Note that you should use `const` qualifier here. The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined (2.13.4/2).

Comment: +1 for `const`-correctness. I hate people disregarding `const`. The ability of the compiler to point out stupid mistakes is severely underrated.