# win32 c++ fstream wide argument

Tags: unicode, winapi, fstream, tchar

See [link](http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/c-unicode.html#streams) for what I'm talking about.

I want to use point 1 in the link and

```
#define tfopen _wfopen
#define _T(s) L##s
```

to do exactly what the link says is possible:

```
std::ifstream file( tfopen("filename.txt", _T("r") );
```

But gcc (mingw) 4.4 says there's no matching call...

Am I doing it wrong or is the info in the link above incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the macro for the first parameter to tfopen, which in your case is "filename.txt"

```
std::ifstream file( tfopen(_T("filename.txt"), _T("r") );
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you're missing a `_T`.  However, you may want to [rethink the entire `TCHAR` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234365/is-tchar-still-relevant/3002494#3002494) and just call `_wfopen` (assuming Windows-only code).

Comment: That's exactly what I decided to do. I have simple toUTF16 and toUTF8 functions to interact with win32 API, and for the rest, I use std::string (UTF-8).