# What is the encoding of argv?

Tags: c, linux, unicode, encoding

It's not clear to me what encodings are used where in C's `argv`. In particular, I'm interested in the following scenario:

- A user uses locale L1 to create a file whose name, `N`, contains non-ASCII characters
- Later on, a user uses locale L2 to tab-complete the name of that file on the command line, which is fed into a program P as a command line argument

What sequence of bytes does P see on the command line?

I have observed that on Linux, creating a filename in the UTF-8 locale and then tab-completing it in (e.g.) the `zw_TW.big5` locale seems to cause my program P to be fed UTF-8 rather than `Big5`. However, on OS X the same series of actions results in my program P getting a `Big5` encoded filename.

Here is what I think is going on so far (long, and I'm probably wrong and need to be corrected):

## Windows

File names are stored on disk in some Unicode format. So Windows takes the name `N`, converts from L1 (the current code page) to a Unicode version of `N` we will call `N1`, and stores `N1` on disk.

What I then *assume* happens is that when tab-completing later on, the name `N1` is converted to locale L2 (the new current code page) for display. With luck, this will yield the original name `N` -- but this won't be true if `N` contained characters unrepresentable in L2. We call the new name `N2`.

When the user actually presses enter to run P with that argument, the name `N2` is converted back into Unicode, yielding `N1` again. This `N1` is now available to the program in UCS2 format via `GetCommandLineW`/`wmain`/`tmain`, but users of `GetCommandLine`/`main` will see the name `N2` in the current locale (code page).

## OS X

The disk-storage story is the same, as far as I know. OS X stores file names as Unicode.

With a Unicode terminal, I *think* what happens is that the terminal builds the command line in a Unicode buffer. So when you tab complete, it copies the file name as a Unicode file name to that buffer.

When you run the command, that Unicode buffer is converted to the current locale, L2, and fed to the program via `argv`, and the program can decode argv with the current locale into Unicode for display.

## Linux

On Linux, everything is different and I'm extra-confused about what is going on. Linux stores file names as *byte strings*, not in Unicode. So if you create a file with name `N` in locale L1 that `N` as a byte string is what is stored on disk.

When I later run the terminal and try and tab-complete the name, I'm not sure what happens. It looks to me like the command line is constructed as a byte buffer, and the name of the file **as a byte string** is just concatenated onto that buffer. I assume that when you type a standard character it is encoded on the fly to bytes that are appended to that buffer.

When you run a program, I think that buffer is sent directly to `argv`. Now, what encoding does `argv` have? It looks like any characters you typed in the command line while in locale L2 will be in the L2 encoding, but **the file name will be in the L1 encoding**. So `argv` contains a mixture of two encodings!

## Question

I'd really like it if someone could let me know what is going on here. All I have at the moment is half-guesses and speculation, and it doesn't really fit together. What I'd really like to be true is for `argv` to be encoded in the current code page (Windows) or the current locale (Linux / OS X) but that doesn't seem to be the case...

## Extras

Here is a simple candidate program P that lets you observe encodings for yourself:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Not enough arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    int len = 0;
    for (char *c = argv[1]; *c; c++, len++) {
        printf("%d ", (int)(*c));
    }
    
    printf("\nLength: %d\n", len);
    
    return 0;
}
```

You can use `locale -a` to see available locales, and use `export LC_ALL=my_encoding` to change your locale.

Comment: In Windows with Visual C's standard library, you can implement wmain() and get a WCHAR * wz_argv[]. If you chose to implement your own C standard library on Windows, you would start at `WinMain` which takes a Unicode string of the entire original command line.  On Windows you surely are running cmd.exe and all the plumbing is Unicode.  As for the Unix-derivatives, the most critical piece of decision-making code, relative to your question, is the shell. E.g., if you are running bash, then the behavior of that version of bash is what you are asking about.

Comment: You can only use a wchar argv on Windows in a commandline app. In a gui build you have to use GetCommandLine separately to for wide chars

Comment: @Martin - I didn't realize that WinMain was also called from the MSVC library, nor that it is ANSI.  Turns out, there is the option of using wWinMain to get Unicode.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101864/windows-unicode-commandline-argv some of it is Qt specific but there is a lot of useful info in the answers

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far. It seems clear that with Windows and wmain (which I mention in my answer) you get UCS-2 encoded Unicode command line arguments. I would suppose that with a Windows main with char** argv you get arguments encoded in the current code page, but this is one of the things I'm unclear on.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your responses. I have learnt quite a lot about this issue and have discovered the following things that has resolved my question:

1. As discussed, on Windows the argv is encoded using the current code page. However, you can retrieve the command line as UTF-16 using GetCommandLineW. Use of argv is not recommended for modern Windows apps with unicode support because code pages are deprecated.
2. On Unixes, the argv has no fixed encoding:

   a) File names inserted by tab-completion/globbing will occur in argv *verbatim* as exactly the byte sequences by which they are named on disk. This is true even if those byte sequences make no sense in the current locale.

   b) Input entered directly by the user using their IME will occur in argv in the locale encoding. (Ubuntu seems to use LOCALE to decide how to encode IME input, whereas OS X uses the Terminal.app encoding Preference.)

This is annoying for languages such as Python, Haskell or [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27923366/how-does-the-jvm-determine-the-default-character-encoding-on-linux), which want to treat command line arguments as strings. They need to decide how to decode `argv` into whatever encoding is used internally for a `String` (which is UTF-16 for those languages). However, if they just use the locale encoding to do this decoding, then valid filenames in the input may fail to decode, causing an exception.

The solution to this problem adopted by Python 3 is a surrogate-byte encoding scheme (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0383/) which represents any undecodable byte in argv as special Unicode code points. When that code point is decoded back to a byte stream, it just becomes the original byte again. This allows for roundtripping data from argv that is not valid in the current encoding (i.e. a filename named in something other than the current locale) through the native Python string type and back to bytes with no loss of information.

As you can see, the situation is pretty messy :-)

Comment: Isn’t the round-tripping a problem because of the restrictions inherent to UTF-16? Wouldn’t something that dealt with UTF-8 or UTF-32 be free of such troubles?

Comment: Not sure what you mean: if Python used UTF-8 strings internally it would still have to use an escaping scheme in order to represent any characters on the command line that could not be decoded using the locale encoding.

Comment: "on Windows the argv is encoded using the current code page. " To be more precise, the ANSI codepage, not the OEM codepage. If you develop console apps, you have to be careful not to confuse the two.

Comment: @YuhongBao are you positive about this? Why would Windows use the ANSI codepage if e.g. chcp shows 437?

Answer (score 8):

I can only speak about Windows for now. On Windows, code pages are only meant for legacy applications and not used by the system or by modern applications. Windows uses UTF-16 (and has done so for ages) for everything: text display, file names, the terminal, the system API. Conversions between UTF-16 and the legacy code pages are only performed at the highest possible level, directly at the interface between the system and the application (technically, the older API functions are implemented twice—one function `FunctionW` that does the real work and expects UTF-16 strings, and one compatibility function `FunctionA` that simply converts input strings from the current (thread) code page to UTF-16, calls the `FunctionW`, and converts back the results). Tab-completion should always yield UTF-16 strings (it definitely does when using a TrueType font) because the console uses only UTF-16 as well. The tab-completed UTF-16 file name is handed over to the application. If now that application is a legacy application (i.e., it uses `main` instead of `wmain`/`GetCommandLineW` etc.), then the Microsoft C runtime (probably) uses `GetCommandLineA` to have the system convert the command line. So basically I think what you're saying about Windows is correct (only that there is probably no conversion involved while tab-completing): the `argv` array will always contain the arguments in the code page of the *current* application because the information what code page (L1) the *original* program has uses has been irreversibly lost during the intermediate UTF-16 stage.

The conclusion is as always on Windows: Avoid the legacy code pages; use the UTF-16 API wherever you can. If you have to use `main` instead of `wmain` (e.g., to be platform independent), use `GetCommandLineW` instead of the `argv` array.

Comment: Thanks, this does confirm what I thought was going on on Windows. Now I hope someone else can clarify the OS X / Linux situation...

Answer (score 2):

The output from your test app needed some modifications to make any sense, 
you need the hex codes and you need to get rid of the negative values.
Or you can't print things like UTF-8 special chars so you can read them.

First the modified SW:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Not enough arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int len = 0;
    for (unsigned char *c = argv[1]; *c; c++, len++) {
        printf("%x ", (*c));
    }

    printf("\nLength: %d\n", len);

    return 0;
}
```

Then on my Ubuntu box that is using UTF-8 I get this output.

```
$> gcc -std=c99 argc.c -o argc
$> ./argc 1ü
31 c3 bc 
Length: 3
```

And here you can see that in my case ü is encoded over 2 chars, 
and that the 1 is a single char. 
More or less exactly what you expect from a UTF-8 encoding.

And this actually match what is in the env LANG varible.

```
$> env | grep LANG
LANG=en_US.utf8
```

Hope this clarifies the linux case a little.

/Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Yep, users has to be careful when mixing locales on Unix in general. GUI file managers that displays and changes filenames also have this problem. On Mac OS X the standard Unix encoding is UTF-8. In fact the HFS+ filesystem, when called via the Unix interfaces, enforces UTF-8 filenames because it needs to convert it to UTF-16 for storage in the filesystem itself.