# Why is hexdump of UTF-16 string when passed in as a command line argument different from what it is directly on the terminal?

Tags: c, bash, utf-16, hexdump, libiconv

In bash, I can get the hexdump of the string `hello` as UTF-16 by doing the following:

```
$  echo -n "hello" | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16 | hexdump
0000000 feff 0068 0065 006c 006c 006f          
000000c
```

I can also write a short C program like so:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char *str = argv[1];

  hexDump("The string", str, 12);

  return 0;
}
```

using the `hexDump` routine from [how to get hexdump of a structure data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775991/how-to-get-hexdump-of-a-structure-data). `12` is the number of bytes I counted from the use of `hexdump` above.

Compile and run:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test


$ ./test $(echo -n hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16)
The string:
  0000  ff fe 68 65 6c 6c 6f 00 53 53 48 5f              ..hello.SSH_
```

Why is there a difference between the first hexstring `feff 0068 0065 006c 006c 006f` and the second hexstring `ff fe 68 65 6c 6c 6f 00 53 53 48 5f`?

I am asking this because I am trying to debug an application that uses `libiconv` to convert a UTF-16 string to UTF-8 and keep getting an `errno` of `EILSEQ` which means that `libiconv` has come across an "invalid multibyte sequence."

**UPDATE:**

If I run `hexdump` with `-C`, I get the following output:

```
$ echo -n hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16 | hexdump -C
00000000  ff fe 68 00 65 00 6c 00  6c 00 6f 00              |..h.e.l.l.o.|
0000000c
```

This hexstring is still different from the one my C program produces in that it includes the `\x00` bytes interspersed between the ascii characters. When I run the C program however, there are no `\x00` bytes interspersed at all. It just has the `ff fe` header and then the regular ascii characters.

Comment: It seems to be a Little Endian vs Big Endian issue.

Comment: I think the root issue of your question is related a bit less to how you *think* you piped it in, but rather what argv is allowed to be encoded as by the OS with regards to locale? See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164430/why-is-it-that-utf-8-encoding-is-used-when-interacting-with-a-unix-linux-environ) for Unix convention, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408730/what-is-the-encoding-of-argv) for more argv-related goodness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `echo -n hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16 | hexdump -C` just pipes data directly between programs. Whatever bytes come out of iconv are taken directly as input to hexdump.

With the command `./test $(echo -n hello | iconv -f ascii -t utf-16)`, the shell takes the output of iconv, and effectively pastes it into a new command, parses the new command, and then executes it.

So the bytes coming out of iconv are: "ff fe 68 00 65 00 6c 00  6c 00 6f 00" and the shell parses this. It appears as though the shell simply skips null bytes when parsing, so the argument input to your program is just the non-null bytes. Since your string is ascii that means the result is just an ascii string (preceded by a UTF-16 BOM).

We can demonstrate this using a character like U+3300 (㌀). If we pass this instead of an ascii character and the above is correct, then the output will include 0x33 (the digit '3').

```
./test $(echo -n ㌀ | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16)
```

My terminal happens to use UTF-8, which supports the character U+3300, so I have iconv convert from that to UTF-16. I get the output:

```
The string:
  0000  ff fe 33                                         ..3
```

---

By the way, your program includes a hard coded size for the array:

```
hexDump("The string", str, 12);
```

You really shouldn't do that. If the array isn't that big then you get undefined behavior, and your post shows some garbage being printed out after the real argument (the garbage appears to be the beginning of the environment variable array). There's really no reason for this. Just use the right value:

```
hexDump("The string", str, strlen(str));
```

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to disable the shell behaviour you describe: " It appears as though the shell simply skips null bytes when parsing".