# Eclipse project cannot include tchar.h

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, cygwin

I am trying to build an lzmat_lib compression library using Eclipse with Cygwin gcc. I downloaded the library from the link [http://www.matcode.com/lzmat_lib.zip](http://www.matcode.com/lzmat.htm).  The file has the following include files:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "lzmat.h"
```

It cannot find the `tchar.h` header file. I do not understand how to add this header file. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Take a look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315566/should-i-eliminate-tchar-from-windows-code

Comment: @KeillRandor Thanks for your suggestion but i just do not know about UTF-8, UTF-16, Unicode etc. i actually can't get that question. :-(

Comment: including <tchar.h> is like including <windows.h>, i.e. it is a windows compiler thing. mingw is not the windows default compiler, so it does not include the windows headers that lzmat_lib needs.

Comment: @KeillRandor does it mean i can't use lzmat_lib file with cygwin gcc.

Comment: Not directly, you'll have to provide a "tchar.h" of your own or remove that include line and see what happens :)

Comment: @KeillRandor it uses a datatype such as _TCHAR which is defined in tchar.h . Can i simply copied tchar.h to my include directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are to install a Windows development environment, like Visual Studio or mingw along with the Windows SDK, or to port the code to your cygwin (posix) environment.

To port the code, you'd just do this:

1. Remove `#include <tchar.h>`.
2. Search and replace `_TCHAR` to `char`.
3. Search the file for all strings beginning with `_t` and remove that prefix.  E.g., `_tfopen` becomes just `fopen`.  `_tprintf` becomes `printf`.
4. Search for the text `_T` and remove it.  You could also remove the extra parentheses that will then surround your string.
5. Deal with any other issues as they come up by removing the dependency on `tchar.h` and using a standard function instead.