# Should string encoding for library conform to Unicode or flexible?

Tags: c++, unicode, stl, mfc, static-libraries

I am created a library in C++ which exposes c style interface APIs. Some of the arguments are string so they would be `char *`. Now I know they should be all Unicode but because it is a library I don't think I want to force users to use decide or not. Ideally I thought it would be best to use `TCHAR` so I can build it either way for unicode code and ASCII users. Than I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234365/is-tchar-still-relevant) and it opposes the idea in general.

As an example of API, the strings are filenames or error messages like below.

```
void LoadSomeFile(char * fileName );
const char * GetErrorMsg();
```

I am using c++ and STL. There is this debate of [std::string vs std::wstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring) as well.
Personally I really like  MFC's CString class which takes care of all this nicely but that means I have to use MFC just for its string class.

Now I think TCHAR is probably the best solution for me but do I have to use CString (internally) for that to work? Can I use it with STL string? As far as I can see, it is either string or wstring there.

Answer (score 1):

The `TCHAR` type is an unfortunate design choice that has thankfully been left behind us.  Nobody has to use `TCHAR` any more, thank goodness.  The Unicode choice has been made for us as well: Unicode is the only sane choice going forwards.

The question is, is your library Windows-only?  Or is it portable?

1. If your library is portable, then the typical choice is `char *` or `std::string` with UTF-8 encoded strings.  For more information, see [UTF-8 Everywhere](http://www.utf8everywhere.org).  The summary is that `wchar_t` is UTF-16 on Windows but UTF-32 everywhere else, which makes it almost useless for cross-platform programming.
2. If your library runs on Win32 only, then you may feel free to use `wchar_t` instead.  On Windows, `wchar_t` is UTF-16.

Don't use both, it will make your code and API bloated and difficult to read.  `TCHAR` is a hack for supporting the Win32 API and migrating to Unicode.

Comment: But if I use `char *` my library will no longer be compatible with unicode applications and vice versa. This will only be used in windows so I don't have to worry about cross compatibility but I do want to make it work with both unicode and non-unicode applications.

Comment: @zadane: Tell your users to pass Unicode strings in by converting them to UTF-8.  Lots of libraries work this way already, I've used several.

Comment: @zadane: I think you may be under the misconception that `char *` is not Unicode.  This is inaccurate, `char *` is really just a data type, and "Unicode" is a way of representing characters.  You can store a Unicode string in `char *` using UTF-8, in `short *` using UTF-16, or in `int *` using UTF-32.  The `wchar_t` type is basically either `short` or `int` (or unsigned versions thereof) depending on whether you're on Windows or somewhere else, but `char *` is available *and consistent* on all common platforms.  (This comment assumes typical widths for integral types.)

Comment: @Deitrich So are you saying I can pass just pass `char *` and still be unicode? In theory that should be fine but I want string that I can easily manipulate as well. The TCHAR does translate to `char *` or `wchar_t` accordingly based on project/encoding settings.

Comment: Yes, you can pass `char *` and still be Unicode.  It is much easier to manipulate than `TCHAR`.  With `TCHAR`, you don't know what encoding you are using and you don't know if it's Unicode at all--very hard to work with, very frustrating.  With `wchar_t`, you don't know what encoding it is but you know it's Unicode -- still frustrating.  If you put UTF-8 in a `char *`, which is incredibly common in C and C++, then you know exactly what encoding you are using--so it is very easy to manipulate strings.  (Note the standard doesn't actually require `wchar_t` to be Unicode, but it is in practice.)

Comment: Keep in mind that `wchar_t` is a variable-length encoding on Windows, so you can't slice strings at arbitrary points.  `TCHAR` could be something monstrous like Shift JIS, which is also variable length.  At least with UTF-8, you know what you are dealing with, and it's compatible with functions like `strlen()`, `snprintf()`, etc.