# Getting size of a TCHAR array

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a 2D `TCHAR` array. I need to covert it to a 1D array. For that I need to get the size of `TCHAR` array.

Suppose `array[i] = "My name";`

Now I need to get the size of `array[i]`. Is there any way I can get that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hopefully you use `const` or `#define` and not magic numbers (like `256`) directly in your code. Then you can just re-use those.

Comment: `array[i] = FindFileData.cFileName;` is an assignment to an array and won't compile.

Comment: 1D-array: `*(TCHAR(*)[sizeof array/sizeof**array)])array`

Comment: I've edited the question. Have a look now

Comment: BTW: You really don't want to use `TCHAR` at all, as there are exactly two valid uses: 1. Describing an API which has both a `char` and a `wchar_t` variant, with identical behavior. 2. Migrating ancient Windows applications (95 or earlier) to a modern Windows.

Answer (score 3):

first add these macroes:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#ifndef UNICODE 
#define tstring std::string
#else
#define tstring std::wstring
#endif

#ifndef _T
#define _T(X) X 
#endif
```

now declare a vector of tstrings:

```
typedef std::vector<tstring> tstrings;

tstrings fileNames;

for(i=0;i<256;i++)
{
    tstring ts = FindFileData.cFileName;
    fileNames.push_back(ts);
}
```

to know the size of a string you just need to use `ts.length()`

Now you can use + to append strings 
like this:

```
tstring ts1 = _T("hello"); 
tstring ts2 = _T("world");
ts1 += _T(" ");
ts1 += ts2;
```

BTW: using array as variable name may cause ambiguity with std::array.

Comment: Please avoid `TCHAR`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869571/getting-size-of-a-tchar-array#comment40482260_25869571

Comment: The high-voted answers are good, the OP accepted a bad one: [Is TCHAR still relevant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234365/is-tchar-still-relevant)

Comment: @Deduplicator The problem is no reason to use only UNICODE when you write cross platform code, especially if your file system encoding is UTF-8. beside of windows, there is no reason to use UNICODE (and wstring) at all. ANYWAY, I think it is a good practice to keep portability.

Comment: @Deduplicator I think the real question is how not to use TCHAR functions and still support UNICODE and NOT UNICODE code. using the string/wstring macro is the better way, at least for my opinion.

Comment: Is it? What statement by the OP indicates that he's not using `TCHAR` *just because*, without understanding what he's letting himself in for with that? Anyway, why don't you avoid some macros by using `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;` instead?

Comment: is `TCHAR` a cross platform type?

Comment: I'm a firm TCHAR partisan, but even I see a WTF in the answer: `#define _T(X) X` is horrid.

Comment: @SHR: No, it is not. But if you compile `TCHAR`-infested code on non-windows, you either hunt them all down and finally clean that codebase up or define `TCHAR`.

Comment: I just prefer to keep it as portable as possible.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I need to get the size of `array[i]`.

Use [`_tcslen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax.aspx) to find the length of a null-terminated array of `TCHAR`, if this is really what you wish to do.

However, you might be better served by:

1. Not using `TCHAR` at all an instead use only UTF-16 encoded text, the platform native encoding.
2. Not using C strings and instead use `std::wstring`.

Comment: Going for all UTF-8 might be even better... or not.

Comment: @Deduplicator First things first eh?!

Comment: For Win32 there is `lstrlen()` function.