# "strncpy_s" Not Working

Tags: c++, strncpy

I'm trying to use strncpy_s to characters from one word to an array (I cannot use strncpy in Visual Studio 2013 and I'm totally new to strncpy_s). I keep getting these errors whatever I do:

> Error 1   error C2660: 'strncpy_s' : function does not take 3 arguments
>
> Error 2   IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "strncpy_s"
>   matches the argument list argument types are: (char *, char, int)

**The purpose of my code is:**

If user inputs, for example, "*HELLO*" (that is, text = HELLO)
Then ->

> ```
> Copy HELLO to first_array [0]
> Copy  ELLO to first_array [1]
> Copy   LLO to first_array [2]
> Copy    LO to first_array [3]
> Copy     O to first_array [4]
> ```

And here's my code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char text[32];
    cin >> text;
    char* first_array[] = {""};
    int n = strlen(text);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        strncpy_s(first_array[i], text[i], n-i);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**. Modified the code a bit more, now the program runs, but after inputing a text, it suddenly gives me the "example.exe stopped working" error.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char* text[32];
    cin >> *text;
    char* first_array[] = {""};
    //int n = strlen(text);
    int n = sizeof(text);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        strncpy_s(first_array[i], n - i, text[i], 32);
    }
```

Comment: [Read the documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dae5d43.aspx)

Comment: `'strncpy_s' : function does not take 3 arguments`... there is your answer, right there. The arguments you passed `are: (char *, char, int)`. That's three arguments, and that's wrong. See remyabel's link, which is actually the top hit when you enter "strncpy_s" in a search engine.

Comment: If this is indeed C++ (as it was originally tagged), then why not use `std::string` and friends?

Comment: Missing #include. @DevSolar to be fair, Microsoft also documents a C++-only 3-argument version.

Comment: Why can't you use `strncpy`? Not saying it would be any better than `strncpy_s`, just a different kind of bad. Anyway, `first_array` is a 1-element array of `char*`, so things are equally bad either way. Also, [avoid `TCHAR`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3002494).

Comment: first_array[i] is not a char pointer

Comment: @paulm actually it seems to be, but it probably shouldn't

Comment: @paulm I think you mean: text[i] is not a char pointer (text+i might be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several issues.

First of all, your call to `strncpy_s` does not follow the [declaration of `strncpy_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dae5d43.aspx), which lists *four* parameters (if the first parameter is a `char *` as in your case):

```
errno_t strncpy_s(
   char *strDest,
   size_t numberOfElements,
   const char *strSource,
   size_t count
);
```

But much more importantly, you state that you would like to end up with multiple strings in an array `first_array[]`, each holding a shorter version of the input string than the last. *But the `first_array[]` you declared only holds **one** `char *` string*, the one you initialized `first_array[0]` to, *which is exactly one character long (the terminating null byte)*:

```
char* first_array[] = {""};
```

Even if you declared it to hold *five* `char *` (the initialization is not necessary as you copy the contents over anyway)...

```
char * first_array[5];
```

...you still haven't allocated *memory space* for each of the five `char *` strings. You just have five pointers *pointing nowhere*, and would have to allocate memory dynamically, *depending on user input*.

Because I haven't even talked about what happens if the user enters more than five characters, let alone 32...

At this point, even if I *would* post "working" code, it would teach you little. You are apparently following some kind of tutorial, or actually attempting to learn by trial & error. I think the right answer here would be:

**Get a different tutorial. Even better, get a [good book on C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or a [good book on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) as online tutorials are notoriously lacking.**

Comment: Thank you very much DevSolar. The problem with types was exactly what made me suspicious. It's great you pointed it out. But, I still do not know which type to use for first_array and for text. I've experimnted with few and none answered.. Can you please guide me a bit on that? And thanks a heap for the helpful links. Definitely gold.

Comment: @gejak: Your problem is a more general one. Your code exhibits **undefined behaviour** in several places (something C/C++ are very unforgiving about), since you apparently haven't grasped the whole pointer / array / memory allocation thing. At this point, telling you how to solve *this* problem will only set you up for failure later on, which is why I linked the books lists. Take a step back and, instead of trying to make this program of yours work, *learn the language you're using, properly*. Other languages are comparatively "safe" to trial & error in. C/C++ are not. You need to **know**.

Comment: @gejak: In case you're really going for C++, you'd be using `std::string`, and not be using `char *` or `strncpy*()` at all. *But you would still need to know how pointers, arrays, and memory handling **work**,* or you will fail dismally at some other, later problem. Explaining language basics is definitely beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question & answer.

Comment: I'll definitely look into that material. I'm still a beginner, and there is still a lot for me out there to learn, but my urge to learn is the reason of my presence on this website, and that is why I regularly look for different examples from different sources and try my best to do it all on my own. But for this one; I've been working for at least 10 hours on it and haven't been able to find the problem. I've looked into tons of different articles. I really can't figure how I should use std::string for my requirement as for first_array and text. How differently should I use string for each?

Comment: @gejak: Again... **do not try to learn C or C++ from looking at sources**. These languages are best learned from **books**, and for good reason. You have to learn the concepts *behind* the code other people have written, or you will remain blind, or at best one-eyed. Even online tutorials are a bad learning source, because they were usually written *by people in the process of learning*. You don't have the experience to spot bad advice, bad habits, and broken examples yourself. **Get a book and learn this from the ground up.** If this code did cost you 10 hours of your life, you know why.