# Get file extension from TCHAR array?

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to get the extension from filename and compare it to my array of extensions. But looks like `TCHAR` do not have `strpos()`-like function, so I am walking an array of `TCHAR` (not the best solution?) to search for the `'.'` sign and extract a file extension. But it doesn't work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < extCount; i++)
{
    //wsprintf(fileName, L"%d", extCount);
    //_tcscpy_s(fileName, extensions[i]);

    _tcscpy_s(fileName, fileData.cFileName);

    for (int k = wcslen(fileName); k >= 0; k--)
    {
        if (fileName[k] == (LPCWSTR)TCHAR('.'))
        {
            wsprintf(temp, L"%c", fileName[k]);
            MessageBox(NULL, fileName[k], L"Файл", MB_OK);
        }
    }
```

So the problem is, how to get and compare the file extension in simpliest and most effective way? And other question is - should I really use `TCHAR`? Because there is so much trouble with this type. When do they used on practice?

Comment: Almost certainly you should not be using TCHAR and almost certainly you should be using one of the std library string classes.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (fileName[k] == L'.')` instead of `fileName[k] == (LPCWSTR)TCHAR('.')` ?

Comment: @Michael Walz , i tried but compiler throws errors for some reason,

Comment: @IvanPetrov: "some error" is not really helpful...

Comment: @ Michael Walz , sorry, i'll provide more info later, because i'am too deep in this TCHAR story. Now i see that there is no strstr()-like function that ignores case. Why didn't the just implemented it?

Comment: You need to listen to all the advice that tells you to stop using `TCHAR`. It will make your life hard for negative benefit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`PathFindExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773587(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows API function (since you're obviously coding for Windows from your posted code). This is in `shlwapi.dll` so you'll need to `#include <shlwapi.h>` and link your project with `shlwapi.lib`.

It returns a pointer to the `'.'` at the beginning of the file extension, so you can just pass this pointer to a string comparison function like `_wcsicmp` to compare it.

By the way, `TCHAR` is a macro that expands to either `char` or `wchar_t` depending on whether your project is built for ANSI or Unicode. It's not a class and doesn't have methods, a `TCHAR` array is just an array of characters.

Comment: Much aprreciated. Thanks to all for examples!

Answer (score 3):

1. There is `TCHAR` version of such function: `tcsstr`;
2. `TCHAR` is pretty outdated thing, use `char/wchar_t`, or even better - `std::string/std::wstring` instead;
3. File name could contain many `.` symbols, so using string search routines seems like an overkill. Simply locate last point in your string and increment string pointer to its index. You will obtain substring with the file extension.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::wstring GetLastExtension(const std::wstring &fileName)
{
    auto pos = fileName.rfind(L".");
    if (pos == std::wstring::npos)
        pos = -1;
    return std::wstring(fileName.begin() + pos, fileName.end());
}
```

Or use the Windows API [PathFindExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

How to compare - [std::wstring::compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/compare/)

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234365/is-tchar-still-relevant) about using TCHAR.
Short: Do not use it.