# GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN); | Gives wrong value| but GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN); gives correct value

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, win32gui

I have a problem with `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);` – the height this function returns is random each time I run the program but the width function, `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);` gives the correct value.

Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>  
#include <stdio.h>   

int  MessageBoxPrintf(const wchar_t * szCaption, const wchar_t * szFormat, ...) {

    wchar_t buffer[1024];
    va_list v1;
    va_start(v1, szFormat);
    wchar_t* c = va_arg(v1, wchar_t*);
    wsprintf(buffer, szFormat, c); //gives formated output to buffer
    va_end(v1);
    return MessageBox(NULL, buffer, szCaption, 0);      
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow) {
    int cxScreen, cyScreen;
    cxScreen = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);  
    cyScreen = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    MessageBoxPrintf(TEXT("ScreenRes"), TEXT("The screen is %i pixels wide by %i pixels high"), cxScreen, cyScreen);
    return 0;
}
```

This program basically just is a Format string Message box with the WinAPI and C++.

Comment: pls tell me how to make the function GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN); return the correct value

Comment: i am giving wchar_t * because i need strings on which i will put placeholders %i and then put the int resolutions of screen obtained from getsystemmetrics()

Comment: One more thing i am beginner , can u clear one more doubt , why and when and where we use TCHAR  . I know its generic way so that we dont have problem with ASI and UTF-16 but in its definition it also says that UNICODE should be defined first , so my question in that when import window.h file does that #if UNICODE .... comes automatically so then i can use TCHAR ?

Comment: If you *know* you want to use `wchar_t` throughout, then just skip all `TCHAR` references and headers, and use `#include <cwchar>` instead of the `tchar.h` header.

Comment: okay , but pls can u tell me in easy words when should i use TCHAR and if possible give a reference website to understand TCHAR pls (other than msdn reference)

Comment: Google is your friend! :) But also, here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40887567/10871073 Or, even better, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/234365/10871073

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have posted shows (almost certainly) undefined behaviour, because of the incorrect way you handle the variadic argument list in your `MessageBoxPrintf` function.

In the `wchar_t* c = va_arg(v1, wchar_t*);` line, you are 'assuming' a single `wchar_t` argument – but, in your `main` function, you are passing **two `int` arguments**. This may or not produce meaningful results; – in your case, it seems that the first `int` argument is correctly interpreted by the subsequent call to `wsprintf` but the second is somewhat "lost in translation" (manifesting the aforementioned undefined behaviour).

To correctly handle that variadic argument list, you need to extract it, then pass it *unprocessed* to the [`vswprintf` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfwprintf), which can then properly interpret that argument list:

```cpp
int MessageBoxPrintf(const wchar_t* szCaption, const wchar_t* szFormat, ...)
{
    wchar_t buffer[1024];
    va_list v1;
    va_start(v1, szFormat);
    vswprintf(buffer, 1024, szFormat, v1);
    va_end(v1);
    return MessageBox(NULL, buffer, szCaption, 0);
}
```

Comment: thnx for the code it works now yeah i made that silly mistake of not using vswprintf