# cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'LPCTSTR'

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, tchar, widestring

I'm trying to convert string to 'LPCTSTR', but, i got following error.

**Error :**

```
cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'LPCTSTR'
```

**code:**

```
std::string str = "helloworld";
LPCTSTR lp = str.c_str();
```

Also, tried :

```
LPCTSTR lp = (LPCTSTR)str.c_str();
```

But, print garbage value.

Comment: Remember the return from `str.c_str()` is a temporary, Also you should not cast here.

Comment: Is `UNICODE` defined in your build system, so that `LPCTSTR` is `LPCWSTR`? If so: consider using `std::wstring`.

Comment: Did you investigate what `LPCTSTR` actually is?

Comment: Just stop using the TCHAR types, they stopped making sense over a decade ago.  Convert char strings to utf16 with mbstowcs() or MultiByteToWideChar().  Or use wchar_t consistently, std::wstring in this snippet.

Answer (score 8):

`LPCTSTR` means (long pointer to constant `TCHAR` string).

A `TCHAR` can either be `wchar_t` or `char` based on what your project settings are.

If, in your project settings, in the "General" tab, your character set is "Use Multi-byte character set" then `TCHAR` is an alias for `char`. However, if it's set to "Use Unicode character set" then `TCHAR` is an alias for `wchar_t` instead.

You must be using the Unicode character set, so:

```
LPCTSTR lp = str.c_str();
```

Is in reality:

```
// c_str() returns const char*
const wchar_t* lp = str.c_str();
```

This is why you're getting the error:

> cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'LPCTSTR'

Your line:

```
LPCTSTR lp = (LPCTSTR)str.c_str();
```

Is in reality:

```
const wchar_t* lp = (const wchar_t*) std.c_str();
```

In a `std::string`, the chars are single bytes, having a `wchar_t*` point to them will expect that each character is 2+ bytes instead. That's why you're getting nonsense values.

The best thing to do would be as Hans Passant suggested - not to use typedefs based on `TCHAR`. In your case, do this instead:

```
std::string str = "helloworld";
const char* lp = str.c_str(); // or
LPCSTR lp = str.c_str();
```

If you want to use wide chars, which Windows calls Unicode, then you can do this:

```
std::wstring wstr = L"helloword";
const wchar_t* lp = wstr.c_str() // or
LPCWSTR lp = wstr.c_str();
```

Comment: Relevant link: [Is TCHAR still relevant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234365/is-tchar-still-relevant/)